# Why am I not able to import metrics from river, its giving this error

Tags: python, numpy, importerror

I am trying to import metrics from river on Colab but there might be some version mismatch in numpy I currently have installed and the one used by river

`from river import metrics`
I am trying to run this and I am getting the below error

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
__init__.pxd in numpy.import_array()

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-3108f4ad0000> in <module>
----> 1 from river import metrics
      2 from river import stream
      3 from river import preprocessing
      4 from river import tree,neighbors,naive_bayes,ensemble,linear_model
      5 from river.drift import DDM, ADWIN, EDDM, PageHinkley, KSWIN, HDDM_A, HDDM_W

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/river/metrics/mutual_info.py in <module>
      4 
      5 from river import metrics
----> 6 from river.metrics.expected_mutual_info import expected_mutual_info
      7 
      8 __all__ = [

build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/river/metrics/expected_mutual_info.pyx in init river.metrics.expected_mutual_info()

__init__.pxd in numpy.import_array()

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Answer (score 0):

this `pip install numpy==1.8.0` solved similiar for me. try upgrading numpy.